# OpenSocial Installation on the server.?

Tags: javafx, opensocial

I would like to ask some question. We have a college project to create
simple social software with JAVA FX(as GUI Framework) and Opensocial.
We would like to connect to MySpace and Co. and retrieve data from
particular network site and updating.

For those purpose, I should have to install OpenSocial on the web
server.? How can I Do it, which web server do i need to use it?

many thanks in advance.

regards,
Koko

Answer (score 1):

This is super late, but I just did it. Try this:

1. Download apache shindig .war file
2. Put it in Tomcats' webapp folder. Delete the ROOT folder. Rename shindig.war to ROOT.war
3. Turn on Tomcat (run startup.bat if you are on windows, make sure JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are set)
4. Point your browser to http://localhost:8080/samplecontainer/samplecontainer.html
5. Put your gadget xml files in /samplecontainer/examples folder
6. Give the URL of your gadget in the UI and click on reset button. Restart tomcat. You should now be able to see your gadget on that page.